# Making summary table of continent wise contribution of research papers in literature using QGIS

Tags: qgis, summarizing

I want to generate a summary table. This table will consists of contribution of each continent in research literature.

I have a CSV file that consists of latitude and longitude information of each affiliation. I am attaching link of [a csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozl94levovp2o4g/jin.csv?dl=0).

I want that kind of table. How can I get it?

[image: example]

Comment: @PolyGeo Sorry I am not from this field. Some body told me this possible in QGIS. Please tell me if it is possible to make such table.

Comment: I’m not a QGIS user but I suspect it is. What have you researched/tried?

Comment: This is a fairly basic GIS task, but it doesn't represent a single problem. I 'd imagine there's be a minimum of 3-5 answered questions which touch on all the individual steps to create such a document

Comment: @Vince please suggest me any tutioral or video.

Comment: @Vince suggest me steps to do it. I shall be very thankful to you

Comment: You will need a vector layer of countries e.g.  https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/  Then you can use the 'Join attributes by location (summary)' tool from the processing toolbox to count the total number of contributing organizations for each country and add the count to the attribute table, then use the Field Calculator to create a percentage column and populate it using a simple percentage calculation.

Comment: You can start your research into these tools and their use here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location-summary  https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator  then refine your question if you encounter a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

The steps of a possible solution are:

1. To solve this task you need a polygon layer of the continents, divided into sun-continents (e.g. Northern Europe, Western Europe, etc.), the sub-continents should have an attribute, the name of sub-continent, load this layer into QGIS.
2. Load your CSV file as a delimited text file into QGIS  (https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html).
3. Make an intersection of the subcontinent and the CSV layer to add the sub-continent name to the CSV records (Processing Toolbox -> Vector Overlay -> Intersection).
4. Make an SQL query on the result of the intersection using DB Manager plugin, you would probably use **GROUP BY sub_continent** clause and **SUM**, **COUNT**, etc. aggregate functions of SQL. (https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_db_manager.html)